# Why this UnboundLocalError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, namespaces

I am quite new to Python and try to understand how it works. Now I ran into a scoping problem that puzzles me.

I think I do understand the following example. I construct a function with an empty local namespace (please correct me if my terminology is not right). When called, it has to print the value of a variable x. That is not in the namespace of the function, so Python looks in the enclosing namespace, finds x there and prints the value.

```
x = 12

def f():
    print(locals())
    print(x)

f()
```

Returns:

```
[]
12
```

I learned from various sources that the namespace of a function is constructed during the evaluation of the function and vanishes when the function evaluation is over. That is what I see in the next example. When the function evaluation starts, only the function argument is in the namespace. Then assignments to y and z are done, resulting in y and z successively being placed in the local name space, as shown by the three printing results in the output.

```
def f(x):
    print(locals())
    y = 20
    print(locals())
    z = x+y
    print(locals())
    return z

f(10)
```

Returns:

```
{'x': 10}
{'x': 10, 'y': 20}
{'x': 10, 'y': 20, 'z': 30}
30
```

Now the subtlety I fail to understand. In the first example, I include an assignment to x just after the print statement.

```
x = 12

def f():
    print(locals())
    print(x)
    x = 24

f()
```

Result:

```
{}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    f()
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 5, in f
    print(x)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

When x has to be printed, it is not yet in the local namespace. So I expected to see the outside value 12. But Python seems to be aware of the fact that x is a local variable of the function and produces an UnboundLocalError.

This suggest to me that when the definition of a function is read, Python creates some or other list with the string names for the local variables, I think including default values for the arguments. This list is then used during the evaluation of the function for constructing the local namespace. Where is this list stored? Very likely, I am completely wrong.  Any help in understanding what is going on here is highly appreciated.